# Accessing parsed data from Parser in ANTLR4

Tags: antlrworks, antlr4

I am processing my input file through my custom grammar and extracting tokens and returning them in a `HashMap`. In ANTLR 3 I was able to parse the file by invoking `rule()` method on parser and getting the `HashMap` something like `parser.record`.

This doesn't seems to work in ANTLR 4. I referred the book and it appears that I have to call `parser.init()` to start parsing but I don't see any method in my parser.

I used ANTLRWorks 2 to generate my lexer and parser files. I didn't generate the listener classes.

Answer (score 5):

In ANTLR 4, you start parsing by calling the method matching the name of the entry rule. If the rule in your grammar is called `rule`, you would start parsing by calling `rule()`. If the rule in your grammar is called `init`, then you would start parsing by calling `init()`.

Note that the Java target in ANTLR 4 does not allow you to have a rule called `rule`, so if you have such a rule in your grammar you'll need to rename it before the grammar will compile.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I am dealing with another problem now. Find below a snippet from my grammar. As you can see, I am saving the values in a HashMap. My file is being parsed correctly but I am not able to access that HashMap post-parsing.In ANTLR 3,it was as simple as parser.metadata . record :
{Map<String,String> metadata = new HashMap<String,String>(); }
  header1 WORD* COLD_JOB WORD+ doctype {metadata.put("doctype",$doctype.text);}
  header2 
  'Transaction Submitted on:' date time
  'CSR Name:' WORD+
  DIGIT 'Customer ID:' customer_number {metadata.put("thriventId",$customer_number.text);}